# Listview row Tooltip Display Duration

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

How can we increase the tool tip display duration when the tooltip has been set using `ToolTipText` property of `ListViewItem` without using a tooltip component?

I have added the tooltip item and attached it with each `ListViewItem` as shown below:

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem("some text"); 
lvi.ToolTipText = "some tooltip";
```

I've also tried adding a tool tip component in below events but it didn't worked out for me: `Listview` `MouseMove` or `MouseEnter` or `ListItemHover`. Also when I set the tooltip using above code, it's not keeping showing long enough.

Comment: can you add a minimal example to you question? In general you can add a `Windows.Forms.Timer()` to your control starting on the `MouseEnter` event. After the duration you want you can use `ToolTip.Hide()` to hide your tooltip.

Comment: I have Tried to explain below.
I have added the tooltip item and attached it with each listviewitem as shown below.
`
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem((listView1.Items.Count + 1).ToString());
lvi.ToolTipText = GetToolTipText(tag.goodsInfoEX.GoodsCode);
`
Adding a tool tip control in below events didn't worked out for me
Listview mouse move or mouseenter or listitemhover

and when added like shown above in listviewitem, the tooptip is not holding long enough.

Comment: @Rahulsapkota I edited the question to make it more useful. Please consider posting details of the question as part of the question.